# after insert,after update trigger doesn't work

Tags: trigger, insert, after-trigger

Below is my trigger to create a new record(with next quarter) when Hold and freeze are set to true.

But this works for new but not update.

below is my trigger and .

```
trigger AddingNewQuarter on Flag__c (after insert,after update) 
{ 
if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isAfter)
{
AddingNewQuarter.createRecord(trigger.new, trigger.newMap);
}
}
```

Handler class

```
public class AddingNewQuarter{
public static void createRecord(List<Flag__c> oclist,Map<Id, Flag__c> newMap){
    oclist= [SELECT Id, Name FROM Flag__c WHERE Id IN :newMap.keySet()];
    for(Flag__c mdmocc:oclist){
      string  name   =   [select Name from Flag__c order by createddate desc limit 1][0].Name;
        boolean hold   =   [select Hold__c from Flag__c order by createddate desc limit 1][0].Hold__c;
        boolean freeze =   [select Freeze__C from Flag__c order by createddate desc limit 1][0].Freeze__C;
        integer quarter = 0;
        integer Year = 0;   if(integer.valueof(name.substring(5,6)) == 4)
{
quarter = 1;
Year = integer.valueof(name.substring(0,4)) + 1; }  else{
  quarter = integer.valueof(name.substring(5,6)) + 1;
  Year= integer.valueof(name.substring(0,4));}string nextquarter =  Year + 'Q' + quarter;
if([select Name from Flag__c where Name = :nextquarter] == null)
{}else{    
{
    if(hold && freeze == true)
      {
        Flag__c mof = new Flag__c ();     
        mof.Name = nextquarter; 
        mof.Hold__c = false ;
        mof.Freeze__c  = false ;
      {    
            insert mof;
        }  
      }
}}}}}
```

Comment: This code needs more help than "doesn't work." You need to fix a lot of problems here.

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please elaborate??

Comment: Queries inside loops, unnecessary queries, code formatting issues, an inverted if statement (why not just say != null instead of using else?), what looks like maybe a DML statement in a loop? Your code is not maintainable as written.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks a ton!! for your feedback.I was grown up by seeing your answers, I felt happy to see your answer on my question. Once again thanks for educating with patience.

Answer (score 2):

Just by checking the code on the trigger, it works only on **after insert**: (`if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isAfter)`).

If you want to work for both cases (on after insert and after update), you have to make just:

```
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
       AddingNewQuarter.createRecord(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
}
```

Comment: why Trigger.isInsert is not required?

Comment: @Doondi if you want the trigger to work for both cases, on after insert and after update, that's all needed because your trigger has only **insert** and **update** events, as your code is: `trigger AddingNewQuarter on Flag__c (after insert,after update)`

Comment: @Doondi you're welcome. Please check the correct answer and/or update the question accordingly to benefit as a future reference for others. Thanks.

Comment: it's solving the timely purpose, but it doesn't stand strong enough to get code coverage. that's why I have left it as it is.

Comment: @Doondi your question doesn't imply that. You've got an answer for what you asked your problem was.

Comment: I tried to update your answer, but I don't have enough credits to do so. I cannot edit question now. so please tell what you want me to do now?

Comment: It's not up to me to tell what you have to do. If the answer did solved your question/issue then accept it as a correct answer, but it's all up to you :)

Comment: Your answer definitely helped me, but I don't know how to make it correct answer. As I told earlier, I did try to update it but I don't have much points.

Comment: Check this [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on meta